# How to trace lock events

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock, trace

I want to implement a deadlock detection algorithm so I need to trace all lock events from my application. The application has more than one million lines of code, so I cannot manually add trace outputs in the code.

Is there any alternative for example get an trace file from .net with clr events?

Comment: What are "lock events"?  I don't think they exist. Raising an event would be a huge overhead compared to taking a lock.

Comment: A lock event is the CLR call to lock an object. I think it is something like `Monitor.Enter`